# Format numbers to integers with SI prefix

Tags: javascript, d3.js, string-formatting

I am drawing a chart, which gets dollar values (from 0 to millions), and I am trying to show nice ticks. I already used d3.nice to get 5 ticks that all have nice values, it's very cool. But since there's such a large variance, I am struggling to display my dollar values correctly.

I wish to do:

- 0-999: shows itself
- 1,000 - 999,999: shows 1k-999k (it's ok if 999,500 shows 1M, but not ok to show 1.00k by using d3.format('.3s'), or having 467k go to 400k by using d3.format('.1s'))
- 1,000,000 - 999,999,999: shows 1M-999M (also ok if it rolls over when rounding)

Prior to d3 version 4, this was easy. You could do:

```
.ticks((d) => {
  var prefix = d3.formatPrefix(d);

  return prefix(d).toFixed()+''+prefix.symbol;
})
```

But now, I am reading the d3 v4 docs after this fails on me, and it says:

> The d3.formatPrefix method has been changed. Rather than returning an SI-prefix string, it returns an SI-prefix format function for a given specifier and reference value. For example, to format thousands:
>
> var f = d3.formatPrefix(",.0", 1e3);
>
> f(1e3); // "1k"
>
> f(1e4); // "10k"
>
> f(1e5); // "100k"
>
> f(1e6); // "1,000k"

This seems impossible to accomplish now, then, because I want to vary the amount of significant digits, but I see no obvious way to accomplish that. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your desired output correctly, you can use the number itself to define the `value` of `d3.formatPrefix`.

Look at this demo:

```js
[1, 999, 1000, 999000, 1000000].forEach(function(d) {
  var prefix = d3.formatPrefix(".0", d)
  console.log(d + ": " + prefix(d))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: Using this approach, `999500` will give you 1000k, not 1M.

Answer (score -1):

Okay well I suppose this was easy enough, but a little hacky. Here's the formatter function I used to make this behaviour:

```
(val) => {
  let prefix = d3.formatPrefix('.3s', val);

  let str = prefix(val);

  if (val === 0) {
    return '0';
  }

  return parseInt(str.slice(0, str.length - 2))+''+str.slice(str.length - 1);
}
```

I would be happy to use something better so if you have a cleaner answer, post and I'll accept.